# How to schedule a cron for gcloud copy(cp) command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We wanted to copy a folder on GCP storage to another back-up folder once in day. Is there anyway to schedule the shell script to perform this activity? The shell script looks something similar,

`gcp-store-backup.sh`

```
destinationPath = constructDestinationPath()
gsutil -m cp -r dir gs://my-bucket/sourceDir gs://my-bucket/destinationPath
```

Comment: How about `crontab -e`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You may also consider scheduling an automatic daily transfer job via [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers)

Comment: If your destination path is dynamic, you have to run the code on a machine (serverless or not). If you find a way to make the destination static, this time you can use built in features.